# expression evaluation does not work

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am attempting to build up an XML document to return from a function as below.  Why does the evaluation substitution work if I use `let` to store it in another variable first? Can I not evaluate the expression in place? As you can see in the result at the end, the resulting XML is only populated with the variable value where I had stored it in the `$x` variable.

```
declare function local:oim-to-canonical($oimContent as node()) {
  let $x := $oimContent/account/domain/text()
  return
    <person xmlns="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/people-db/model">
      <account>
        <domain>{ $oimContent/account/domain/text()  }</domain>
        <username>{ $oimContent/account/username/text() }</username>
        <status>{ $oimContent/account/status/text() }</status>
        <x>{ $x }</x>
      </account>
    </person>
};

local:oim-to-canonical(
  <person>
    <account>
      <domain>MYDOMAIN</domain>
      <username>ttt</username>
      <status>ENABLED</status>
    </account>
  </person>
)
```

Results in:

```
<person xmlns="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/people-db/model">
  <account>
    <domain/>
    <username/>
    <status/>
    <x>MYDOMAIN</x>
  </account>
</person>
```

Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the comment after the answer you wrote, you're right that wildcarding the namespace in the XPath will work:

```
<domain>{ $oimContent/*:account/*:domain/text()  }</domain>
```

However, this is considered a bad practice when it's avoidable. In order to execute that XPath, MarkLogic needs to do more work than if the namespace is provided. The challenge is that your input XML is using the empty namespace and there's no way to specify that. I would modify the input to use a namespace:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace inp = "input";

declare function local:oim-to-canonical($oimContent as node()) {
  let $x := $oimContent/inp:account/inp:domain/text()
  return
    <person xmlns="http://schemas.abbvienet.com/people-db/model">
      <account>
        <domain>{ $oimContent/inp:account/inp:domain/text()  }</domain>
        <username>{ $oimContent/inp:account/inp:username/text() }</username>
        <status>{ $oimContent/inp:account/inp:status/text() }</status>
        <x>{ $x }</x>
      </account>
    </person>
};

local:oim-to-canonical(
  <person xmlns="input">
    <account>
      <domain>MYDOMAIN</domain>
      <username>ttt</username>
      <status>ENABLED</status>
    </account>
  </person>
)
```

This allows your XPath to be more explicit. Small scale, the difference may not matter, but at scale the difference adds up.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with Dave that using a namespace for the input makes life easier. Just for the sake of completeness, you can also prevent the issue by not using literal XML with a default namespace, but by using element constructors instead:

```
declare variable $ns := "http://schemas.abbvienet.com/people-db/model";

declare function local:oim-to-canonical($oimContent as node()) {
  let $x := $oimContent/account/domain/text()
  return
    element { fn:QName($ns, "person") } {
      element { fn:QName($ns, "account") } {
        element { fn:QName($ns, "domain") } { $oimContent/account/domain/text()  },
        element { fn:QName($ns, "username") } { $oimContent/account/username/text() },
        element { fn:QName($ns, "status") } { $oimContent/account/status/text() },
        element { fn:QName($ns, "x") } { $x }
      }
    }
};

local:oim-to-canonical(
  <person>
    <account>
      <domain>MYDOMAIN</domain>
      <username>ttt</username>
      <status>ENABLED</status>
    </account>
  </person>
)
```

I usually prefer literal XML though, as it is more dense/less clutter..

HTH!